# automatically pre-caching webpages

Tags: php, html, caching, memory, include

Currently, my website employs a caching system where newly requested pages are generated then cached on the fly for future faster execution. The format overall is this in pseudo code:

```
See if cached page exists.
If cached page exists then
         Load cached page
         Exit
If cached page does not exist then
         Generate page
         Save output to cache file
         Exit
```

Every newly requested page takes between 250 and 500 ms of load time and every cached page takes between 100 and 200 ms of load time.

What I want to do is upon every manual website update, I want to pre-cache the pages (I think its called cache priming).

My cache system is done in PHP and I thought of making a wrapper PHP script that calls the main script that generates the webpage with the appropriate parameters loaded. In Code, this is my thought:

```
<?php
//wrapper script to pre-cache 500 pages
for ($sect=1;$sect<500;$sect++){
    $_GET['param1']="sectiontocache";
    $_GET['sectionno']=$sect;
    include "index.php";
}
?>
```

and index.php (which requires a good chunk of memory) outputs the correct HTML based on input parameters.

I feel if I did it this way, I'd either place a huge burden on the server and or receive out of memory errors since on each website update, at least 100 to 500 pages need to be cached to deliver optimal performance on every request made by any client.

If I could do something like this:

```
<?php
//wrapper script to pre-cache 500 pages
for ($sect=1;$sect<500;$sect++){
    $_GET['param1']="sectiontocache";
    $_GET['sectionno']=$sect;
    include "index.php";
    declude "index.php";
}
?>
```

Then I'd be happy.

Yes I'm aware declude isn't a valid keyword, but the point I'm trying to make is I want to release memory from the index script after it has been processed so I don't run into errors.

I'm just wondering if I should still use the first php script I have shown and pray the server wont crash, or if theres a better official way to pre-cache pages in my situation.

Comment: dont roll your own look at some of the existing server cache options

Comment: Why bother? The first person to visit a newly updated page has to wait 200-300 milliseconds longer, _on that occasion_. They won't notice. Some pages won't be visited between updates, so no problem there. This looks like a solution looking for a problem.

Comment: My pages contain adsense code and one thing I notice google looks at is page speed. If a page is too slow, it goes lower in the search index which means fewer people will come across it which in turn means lower impressions=lower clicks=lower income.

Comment: If you had **proof** of this you would be the first

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you this solution:

Create a page which include a javascript timer (let's say you need 1 sec to generate one page) :

Each 1 sec , refresh the page by javascript including the next $sect as a GET parameter.

Get the parameter value in your php code, generate the page.

In Javascript, add a condition to stop the process if $sect if > 500

I hope I am clear in my explanations.

Comment: This solution require you load the page in a browser, it cannot be used with a cron task for example.

Comment: so keep a browser window open at all time - seriously?

Comment: @Dagon well it depends. If he need to rebuild the cache once a week, it could fit to his needs. If it's every 20 min, for sure, it makes no sense.

Comment: Also I am not expert with that, but take a look on `ob_flush` functionalities

Comment: Zeflex, your answer would actually require multiple requests to the server which slows down website updating time at best if I used it and ob_flush is what I use in my PHP code just before a new (uncached) page is created. I'd rather have a solution that can be executed on the server without the need for a client to constantly connect to the server to pre-cache each page. Sorry zeflex if I was unclear on that.

Comment: @Mike no problem. For you, what is the ideal time to generate the 500 pages in order to be cached ? I may have another solution, excepts if they should be generated as fast as possible. Also, why do you need to generate a full pages cache instead of generate "the" page cache when a visitor loads "the" page ?

Comment: The faster, the better, and I want to generate the full cache in advance so the visitor doesn't have to wait while the cache is generated in the background which is effectively what I got going on now for the new pages which is why I posted my question

Comment: Before doing the work, check the memory consummed... Maybe you want to do something that is not necessary.